# Can't run the animation demo in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I read the *angular animation doc* and *recreated* the *demo*. 
If you click the `Fold In` button, the text will be changed as the `animate define`.
The *demo* does not work well. The *animation* doesn't work well.

This is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/jiexishede/5nokogfq/

In the Webstorm:
 I change `var app = angular.module('app', []);` as `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);`. 
The error show :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$isDocumentHiddenProvider <- $$isDocumentHidden <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile <- $$animateQueue
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24isDocumentHiddenP…eQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4511
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4664)
    at angular.js:4516
    at getService (angular.js:4664)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4688)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4710)
    at angular.js:4517
    at getService (angular.js:4664)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4688)
```

*If you know how to fix this bug, please write the good demo. I will vote your answer right now.*

Comment: could you provide this in a fiddle or the likes?

Comment: I don't see you included `ngAnimate` module in your `app`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jiexishede/5nokogfq/

Comment: @BryantJackson,@PankajParkar, I have edited the question.

Comment: The other error apart from creating the different module is that ,your angular-animate.js versions to 1.2.1 and there has been a lot of [changes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) which cause the improper functioning of it.

Comment: @pritishvaidya In your opinion, which answer was the best? There were two answers.

Comment: of course the answer of @Ron Dadon is great but since the original idea was of *fingerpich* i would consider it as the right answer,but it is up to you whichever you may like :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've copied the JS from your fiddler:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
   angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']).animation('.fold-animation', ['$animateCss', function($animateCss) {
            return {
                enter: function(element, doneFn) {
                    var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
                    return $animateCss(element, {
                        addClass: 'red large-text pulse-twice',
                        easing: 'ease-out',
                        from: { height:'0px' },
                        to: { height:height + 'px' },
                        duration: 10 // one second
                    });
                }
            }
        }]);
   angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']).controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

    })
```

What you are doing wrong is using the `module` "setter" function multiple times.

In the first line you wrote:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
```

That will define a new module called `app` and assign the module instance to the `app` variable.

From here, you can not declare a module with the name `app` again, only get the instance of this module.

When using `angular.module` function with 2 arguments, you are using the "setter" that will create a new module.
To get the instance, use `angular.module` function with only the module name argument.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);    
var app = angular.module('app');
```

So to fix your code:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
angular.module('app').animation('.fold-animation', ['$animateCss', function($animateCss) {
            return {
                enter: function(element, doneFn) {
                    var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
                    return $animateCss(element, {
                        addClass: 'red large-text pulse-twice',
                        easing: 'ease-out',
                        from: { height:'0px' },
                        to: { height:height + 'px' },
                        duration: 10 // one second
                    });
                }
            }
        }]);
angular.module('app').controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

    })
```

Comment: more or less the same as answered by @fingerpich

Comment: Thank you for alerting me my error that `angular.module('app')` to get the instance.

Comment: @pritishvaidya but it has more description, and this question needs to it.

Answer (score 0):

create your module like this

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
```

and then you can access your module by `angular.module('app')` or `app`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.animation('.fold-animation', ['$animateCss', function($animateCss) {
  return {
    enter: function(element, doneFn) {
      var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
      return $animateCss(element, {
        addClass: 'red large-text pulse-twice',
        easing: 'ease-out',
        from: { height:'0px' },
        to: { height:height + 'px' },
        duration: 10 // one second
      });
    }
  }
}]);

app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
})
```

```css
.red { background:red; color: purple}
        .large-text { font-size:20px; }

        /* we can also use a keyframe animation and $animateCss will make it work alongside the transition */

        .pulse-twice {
            animation: 0.5s pulse linear 2;
            -webkit-animation: 0.5s pulse linear 2;
        }

        @keyframes pulse {
            from { transform: scale(0.5); }
            to { transform: scale(1.5); }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
            from { -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); }
            to { -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); }
        }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>

<body  ng-app="app" ng-controller="myctrl">
<div ng-if="onOff" class="fold-animation">
    This element will go BOOM
</div>
<button ng-click="onOff = true">Fold In</button>
</body>
```